# Using Play 2.4 Scala and Slick, how to select a specific database for running specs2 tests?

Tags: scala, slick, specs2, playframework-2.4

This must be a basic question but I am truly lost here after spending hours on this issue.
I have followed the Play documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlick). I got 2 databases configured (default and test) and DatabaseConfig via Dependency Injection, just like indicated.
This is my repository:

```
package dal
import javax.inject.{ Inject, Singleton }
import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

import models.Cat
import scala.concurrent.{ Future, ExecutionContext }

@Singleton
class CatRepository @Inject() (dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {
    def create( name: String ) : Future[Long] = ...
    def update( id: Long, name: String ): Future[Long] = ...
}
```

and the content of application.conf:

```
slick.dbs.test.driver="slick.driver.H2Driver$"
slick.dbs.test.db.driver="org.h2.Driver"
slick.dbs.test.db.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"

slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cat"
slick.dbs.default.db.user="cat"
slick.dbs.default.db.password="cat"
```

Now, as a first step, I just would like to know how to simply set the "test" database, so I can get a new repository and run my spec2 tests against it.

Thank you for helping.